# Why is my MenuFlyoutItem text binding not working?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mvvm-light

The binding to the `ItemsSource` list is working. I can tell because the list contains four items and, when I test, my flyout menu also has four items. The problem is each `MenuFlyoutItem` is blank. In the code below, `SourceForCompaniesList` is an `ObservableCollection` of type Company. CompanyName is a string property of Company. I have successfully binded to this list in combo boxes, but I cannot make it work in the flyout menu. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <Flyout helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thePage, Path=DataContext.SourceForCompaniesList}" x:Name="theFlyout">
        <helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{Binding ElementName=theFlyout,Path=DataContext.CompanyName}" />
            </DataTemplate>                                                             
        </helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
    </Flyout>                                                       
</FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

Screenshot of open menu:

[image: Screenshot of open menu]

Comment: Are you sure the `Binding Path` is correct? Can you show what context you are using and how you bind it?

Comment: I'm sure that the top level flyout binding is correct. But something is wrong in the MenuFlyoutItem binding.  CompanyName is definitely a property of Company, which is the type of items contained in the SourceForCompanies list. But, I must have something wrong with the path somehow ... I'm guessing it's not binding with the SourceForCompanies list, but I don't know why.

Comment: I am attempting to use the context of the flyout that contains the data template. This is apparently not working. SourceForCompaniesList is an Observable collection in the viewmodel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item `Text` binding can be rewritten in a simpler way which should work correctly:

```
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <Flyout helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thePage, Path=DataContext.SourceForCompaniesList}" x:Name="theFlyout">
        <helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{Binding CompanyName}" />
            </DataTemplate>                                                             
        </helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
    </Flyout>                                                       
</FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

Note I am using just `CompanyName`, as the context of the `DataTemplate` is actually a single `Company` from the bound items source, so you are binding *relative* to the company item itself.

Note, to get an even better performance, you can use `x:DataType` and `x:Bind`:

```
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <Flyout helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thePage, Path=DataContext.SourceForCompaniesList}" x:Name="theFlyout">
        <helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="YourXmlNamespace:Company">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{x:Bind CompanyName}" />
            </DataTemplate>                                                             
        </helpers:BindableFlyout.ItemTemplate>
    </Flyout>                                                       
</FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

Where you need to declare the `YourXmlNamespace` in the root element (most likely a `Page`) as a `xmlns` namespace. This version is more performant, as it uses compiled binding (`x:Bind`) instead of reflection-based `Binding`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I had tried {Binding Company}, but not {Binding CompanyName}. That makes total sense after reading your explanation.

Comment: Glad it helped!